# How can I remove the 'OK' button from a .bat file message box?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

```
echo msgbox "Hey! Here is a message!" > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
wscript %tmp%\tmp.vbs
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

The above message box will disappear if I press any key. I want the box to go away if I press a key, but currently it  goes off only if I click on somewhere in the box.

And I hope that short text will be shown in the taskbar when the box is there.

What should I do to make it go away if I press any button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this which is pure batch script creating an HTA file that has a timer set to auto close which is set as a variable within the logic up top.

This script basically builds an HTA file for the pop up window and then builds the VBS file and then calls it just as you were doing from the `%tmp%` location.

I wasn't able to figure out another way to have the VBS message box just omit the `OK` button or any other buttons for that matter.

**NOTE:** *Just set the variables up top and the rest will build dynamically.  If you need further adjustments that you cannot figure out, just let me know and I can update easily for the most part in a timely fashion once I see it.*

**EXAMPLE BATCH SCRIPT**

```
@ECHO ON 

SET MsgTitle=Hey! Here is a Title!
SET MsgLine1=Hey! Here is a message!
SET MsgLine2=Message Line Two.
SET MsgLine3=Message Line Three.
::: -- Set the number in seconds you want the window to close
SET CloseTimer=5
SET TmpHTAFile=%tmp%\tmp.hta
SET TmpVBSFile=%tmp%\tmp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TmpHTAFile%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpHTAFile%"
IF EXIST "%TmpVBSFile%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpVBSFile%"

ECHO ^<html^>                                                       >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<head^>                                                       >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<hta:application                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO APPLICATIONNAME = "Message Alert"                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ID = "Message Alert"                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO BORDERSTYLE = "Normal"                                         >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO CAPTION = "No"                                                 >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO CONTEXTMENU = "No"                                             >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO INNERBORDER = "No"                                             >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "No"                                          >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO MINIMIZEBUTTON = "No"                                          >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO NAVIGABLE = "No"                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO SCROLL = "No"                                                  >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO SCROLLFLAT = "No"                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO SELECTION = "No"                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO SHOWINTASKBAR = "No"                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO SINGLEINSTANCE = "Yes"                                         >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO SYSMENU = "No"/^> ^<STYLE^>                                    >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO html, body {                                                   >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO background color: #000000                                      >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  font-size: 90%;                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  line-height: 2.1em;                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  margin: 10;                                                   >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  padding: 0;                                                   >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO }                                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO h1 {font-family: Arial;                                        >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  color: #FF0000;                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  font-size: 3em;                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  text-align: center;                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO }                                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO h2 {font-family: Arial;                                        >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  color: #ffffff;                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  font-size: 1.5em;                                             >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  text-align: left;                                             >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO }                                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO h3                                                             >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO {font-family: Arial;                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  color: #666666;                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  font-size: 1em;                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO  text-align: center;                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO }                                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^</STYLE^> ^<script type='text/vbscript'^> Sub Window_onload() >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO me.ResizeTo 500,280                                            >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO me.MoveTo Screen.Width /2 - 300,Screen.Height / 2 - 300        >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO me.SetTimeout "Me.Close()",%CloseTimer%000                     >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO End Sub                                                        >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^</script^>                                                    >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^</head^>                                                      >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<body scroll="no"^>                                           >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<br^>                                                         >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<h1^>%MsgTitle%^</h1^>                                        >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<h2^>%MsgLine1%^<br^>                                         >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO %MsgLine2%^<br^>                                               >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO %MsgLine3%^</h2^>                                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<h3^>close in %CloseTimer% seconds^</h3^>                     >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^<script type="text/javascript"^>                              >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^</script^>                                                    >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^</body^>                                                      >> "%TmpHTAFile%"
ECHO ^</html^>                                                      >> "%TmpHTAFile%"

ECHO Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")           >> "%TmpVBSFile%"
ECHO objShell.Run ("%TmpHTAFile%")                                  >> "%TmpVBSFile%"
wscript "%TmpVBSFile%"
DEL /Q /F "%TmpVBSFile%"
```

**RESOURCE:** *http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/how-to-create-a-customised-popup-notification-window-using-hta*

---

**EXAMPLE BATCH (using zero second argument)**

*(Using this method appears to only close the VBS message box windows with you press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> or <kbd>**Space Bar**</kbd> when it is the active window)*

```
ECHO msgbox "Hey! Here is a message!",0,"My Title!">"%tmp%\tmp.vbs"
WSCRIPT "%tmp%\tmp.vbs"
IF EXIST "%tmp%\tmp.vbs" DEL /Q /F "%tmp%\tmp.vbs"
```

**RESOURCE:** *http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html*

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I think I did not ask the question clearly. I have just edited my question. Please read it again.